# Customization point with user-defined implementation within a designated namespace

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, customization, argument-dependent-lookup

Is it possible to provide a customized implementation within a user-defined namespace?
For example, I want a user to implement customization points within a specific namespace, for example `namespace custom`.

This is an example that works, but not the way I would like to have it:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace custom
{
    // this does not help. Will result in undefined symbol
    template <typename T>
    void print(const T&);
}

namespace eld
{
    namespace detail
    {
        template<typename T>
        void print(const T &)
        {
            std::cout << "Generic version" << std::endl;
        }

        struct print_fn
        {
            template<typename T>
            void operator()(const T &t) const
            {
                // using custom::print; // this will result in undefined symbol
                print(t);
            }
        };

        template<typename T>
        struct static_constexpr
        {
            static constexpr T value{};
        };

        template<typename T>
        constexpr T static_constexpr<T>::value;
    }

    namespace
    {
        constexpr const auto &print = detail::static_constexpr<detail::print_fn>::value;
    }
}

struct foo
{
};

namespace custom
{
    // this will never be called
    void print(foo) { std::cout << "Custom Implementation for foo" << std::endl; }

    struct bar{};

    void print(bar)
    {
        std::cout << "Custom implementation with ADL for custom::bar" << std::endl;
    }
}

// this will be called
void print(foo) { std::cout << "Implementation for foo" << std::endl; }

int main(int, char **)
{
    eld::print(4);
    eld::print(foo());
    eld::print(custom::bar());

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Generic version
Implementation for foo
Custom implementation with ADL for custom::bar
```

What I **want** is for `custom::print(foo)` to be used. It is a preferred way, since some other functions with the same name may be visible in a global namespace. I might use some name prefixes to circumvent this problem, but I'd rather use a designated namespace. Is it possible? (11, 14, 17 Standard)

---

This is an approach I use now, which works but has some inconveniences:

- a user must "copy-paste" forward declaration of a class template in order to customize it, if a header with implementation is used as a standalone header.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace eld
{
    namespace custom
    {
        template <typename T>
        struct print
        {
            void operator()(const T&)
            {
                std::cout << "Generic version" << std::endl;
            }
        };
    }

    template <typename T>
    void print(const T& t)
    {
        eld::custom::print<T>{}(t);
    }
}

struct foo
{
};

template <>
struct eld::custom::print<foo>
{
    void operator()(const foo&)
    {
        std::cout << "Custom Implementation for foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    eld::print(4);
    eld::print(foo());

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jb5rbbY7a

Comment: Namespaces are not something that can be dependent on its own. ADL only works because the argument *type* is dependent, and the namespaces pulled in are very specific. Why does it *have* to be a namespace alone? A class template a-la `template<class C> struct print_custom;` can serve as customization point.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica until this point I have been using functional objects as customization points. It does not utilize ADL and can be explicitly redefined using partial class template specialization. `struct custom::print<foo>{ void operator()(const foo&);};` will do the thing. There are some inconveniences though. And moreover, I would like to stick to more "mainstream" ways of defining customization points.

Comment: Call me naive, but [`std::formatter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter) is very "mainstream" IMO. How about using the right tool for the job rather than appeal to popularity? You won't get your approach to work.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I've updated my question with the details of my current *working* approach. I find it very unsafe and limiting to pollute global namespace with customization points. I am talking about making customizable and reusable libraries

Comment: Who said anything about polluting the global namespace? And your *proper* approach is not polluting anything. *"I am talking about making customizable and reusable libraries*" - Oh, thanks for clearing *that* up.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Idk what you found to be so upsetting in my comment. What I mean is that you can make a free function in a global namespace, but if you are using other libraries there is a chance of name clashing. Adding prefixes/suffixes is rather ugly (though working). http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/ This article **does** say about polluting global namespace. Without prefixes one would waste a lot of time figuring out that his *swap-like* named function has broken everything. Designated namespace for customization are better IMO